# inherit and individual styles in css

Tags: css

I am making a newsletter for emails. That contains of 30 columns that all have th following class:

```
.content-text {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3;

  }
```

Each column need to have the above class, but each column need to have different background colors. Example:

```
.column--left__content {
    background-color: #bebab1;
  }
```

So that would say that column--left__content should inherit everything from content-text. How can I do that the best way?

**HTML**

```
<table class="row">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="small-12 large-1 columns first first--column__color " style="width:1%;">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <p></p>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
      <!-- Here is how I solved this until now -->
      <th class="small-12 large-5 columns first content-text column--left__content">
        <table >
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h5><strong>This is headline 1</strong></h5>
              <p class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </th>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

At the moment I am calling the `content-text` and `column--left__content` in the sam `<th>`, which does not look so nice.

The best practice for doing this, how would that be? I am thinking that fx `column--left__content` have to inherit `.content-text`, but have individually styles also?

**EDIT**

The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use the `nth-child` selector in CSS.

```css
.wrapper {
color:#fff;
background-color:none;
width:50%;
height:3rem;
line-height:3rem;
font-size:1.5rem;
}
.wrapper p {
padding:0 0 0 1rem;  
}
.wrapper p:nth-child(1) {
background: red;
}
.wrapper p:nth-child(2) {
background: green;
}
.wrapper p:nth-child(3) {
background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p> col 1</p>
    <p> col 2</p>
    <p> col 3</p>
</div>
```

Another possible way is to create your own `background-color` helper classes in order to use whenever you want to and not only to use for this case.

```css
.wrapper {
color:#fff;
background-color:none;
width:50%;
height:3rem;
line-height:3rem;
font-size:1.5rem;
}
.wrapper p {
padding:0 0 0 1rem;  
}
.bg_red {
background: red;
}
.bg_green {
background: green;
}
.bg_brown {
background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="bg_red"> col 1</p>
    <p class="bg_green"> col 2</p>
    <p class="bg_brown"> col 3</p>
</div>
```

There is a 3rd way that has to do with a small jQuery plugin i have made once (i have not updated it though :) since there was no real usage). But the concept is to use simple helper classes for text-color and background-color in your syntax. The rest is done by the plugin. The class that have to just be added in your HTML (nothing in CSS is needed) have the prefix (bgDarken-,bgLighten-,txtDarken-,txtLighten-) and are followed by a number between 1 and 256. Check the results in the snippet.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/petergd/jLightenDarken), there are two examples one using `Bootstrap` (and is posted here in the snippet), and one using `Materialize` framework.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>jLightenDarken Demo with Bootstrap Framework integration.</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
body {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
div.alert, div.panel {
background-color:#2196f3;
    color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-4">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-4 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-8">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-8 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-16">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-16 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-24">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-16 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-40">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-48">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-64">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-80">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-16 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-96">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-124">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-140">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-148">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-156">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-164">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-192">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-24 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-224">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-16 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default bgDarken-255">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer bgLighten-16 txtDarken-255"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...</div>
 </div>
    </div>

</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-16">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-24">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-32">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-40">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-48">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-56">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-64">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-80">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-96">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-124 txtDarken-124">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-156 txtDarken-156">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-164 txtDarken-164">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-180 txtDarken-180">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-192 txtDarken-196">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-216 txtDarken-224">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-232 txtDarken-248">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
<div class="alert alert-info bgLighten-256 txtDarken-256">         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus neque, pretium eget elit sit amet, maximus pretium libero...                     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">!function(n){function t(n){return null==n||""==n||"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"===n||"transparent"===n}function o(n){var i=n.parent(),r=n.css("background-color");return t(r)&&(r=i&&null!=i?o(i):""),r}function r(n){var i=n.parent(),o=n.css("color");return t(o)&&(o=i&&null!=i?r(i):""),o}function s(n){var t=n.split("-"),i=[];return 2==t.length?(i.functionality=t[0],i.amount=parseInt(t[1]),i):void 0}function l(t){var o,l,a,e,h=[],c=[],u=[];for(e=0,j=0;j<t.length;j++){"txtLighten"==t&&(e=1),"txtDarken"==t&&(e=-1),o=n('div[class*="'+t+'"]');var g,f=0,p=[];for(n.each(o,function(){for($klassKolor=r(n(this)),p.push($klassKolor.match(/\d+/g)),h.push($klassKolor),l=n(this).prop("class").split(" "),k=0;k<l.length;k++)-1!=l[k].search(t)&&(a=s(l[k]),c.push(a.amount))}),f=0;f<p.length;f++){for(g=p[f],i=0;i<g.length;i++)g[i]=parseInt(g[i])+c[f]*e,g[i]>=255&&(g[i]=255),g[i]<=0&&(g[i]=0),g[i]=g[i].toString(16),g[i].length<2&&(g[i]="0"+g[i]);u.push("#"+g.join(""))}}n.each(o,function(t){n(this).css("color",u[t])})}function a(t){var r,l,a,e,h=[],c=[],u=[];for(e=0,j=0;j<t.length;j++){"bgLighten"==t&&(e=1),"bgDarken"==t&&(e=-1),r=n('div[class*="'+t+'"]');var g,f=0,p=[];for(n.each(r,function(){for($klassKolor=o(n(this)),p.push($klassKolor.match(/\d+/g)),h.push($klassKolor),l=n(this).prop("class").split(" "),k=0;k<l.length;k++)-1!=l[k].search(t)&&(a=s(l[k]),c.push(a.amount))}),f=0;f<p.length;f++){for(g=p[f],i=0;i<g.length;i++)g[i]=parseInt(g[i])+c[f]*e,g[i]>=255&&(g[i]=255),g[i]<=0&&(g[i]=0),g[i]=g[i].toString(16),g[i].length<2&&(g[i]="0"+g[i]);u.push("#"+g.join(""))}}n.each(r,function(t){n(this).css("background-color",u[t])})}n.fn.jLightenDarken=function(){l("txtLighten"),l("txtDarken"),a("bgLighten"),a("bgDarken")}}(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').jLightenDarken();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Summing up, depending on what you really want each one of those or any other answer presented by other SO users could be the best (or not) solution for **YOU**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you HTML is as follow:

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <div class="col1"> col 1</div>
    <div class="col2"> col 2</div>
    <div class="col3"> col 3</div>
</section>
```

your CSS could be like this:

```
.wrapper > div {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

and have a color for each class:

```
.col1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.col2 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just updated my question. If you have time I would like you took a look at it. Would you still mean that your solution is the best way?

Comment: The principle would still apply, you can have one generic class for your generic style (that would imply having 30 classes doing the same thing, personally I prefer my solution above ".wrapper > div") and  have a specific class for each color... To answer your question.. yes

Answer (score 0):

One good Choice would be too use CSS Less . You can use @extend concept of CSS Less.

```
.contest-test {
   .context-text(); /* Copies everything from .context-text down here */
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Follow this [Link](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/07/learn-less-in-10-minutes-or-less/) here

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have to use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First: if *every single iteration of an element* has *the same* class, you're doing things wrong.

Second: You can easily fix your problem by not assigning a class, but giving the base CSS to the element itself.

For instance something like this:

```
th {
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.3;
}
```

And then you just add the background-color classes as you need them.